# Data tools project ambiguous reference error that doesn't occur in database

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

I'm trying to create SQL Server Data Tools database project that will reflect an existing database. I compared it against the target but for the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetActiveStockMultilingual] @ListSize INT AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP(@ListSize)
        Bs.BookId,
        BTs.Title
    FROM Books Bs
    JOIN BookTitles BTs ON Bs.BookId = BTs.BookId
    WHERE Bs.Active = 1 
    ORDER BY BookId DESC
END
```

I get the following error:

> Procedure: [dbo].[GetActiveStockMultilingual] contains an unresolved reference to an object. Either the object does not exist or the reference is ambiguous because it could refer to any of the following objects: [dbo].[Books].[BookId] or [dbo].[BookTitles].[BookId].

I agree with what the error says: the reference is ambiguous. But the problem is that SQL Server itself doesn't treat this as an issue. When I recreate the procedure in database or run the query itself there are no errors.

I searched through similar questions but in those that I could find the problem was caused by the fact that one of the referenced tables was located in another database. This is not the case here, both objects share the same database.

This is the only error that my project shows but there are plenty of warnings with similar descriptions.

I would prefer to leave the procedure unchanged. Is there something that I should modify in the properties of my project so that it would stop showing this error? Or maybe there is some article that explains the discrepancy between the database and my project so I could justify the change in the procedure to more senior members of my team?

Comment: Qualify your column in `ORDER BY BookId DESC`. Presumably it should `BS.BookID`.

Comment: Let's throw in some additional best practices. Always qualify every column reference with the associated alias. Schema-qualify your object names. Use statement terminators. And **talk** to your group members. You won't learn collectively if you hide from each other and avoid asking questions. Senior members should be willing to discuss any question or issue. If that is not the case, you have a dysfunctional organization.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason here to not modify the procedure, as it is technically already broken -- I know of no documentation that guarantees which table an unqualified column in an `ORDER BY` will resolve to. Adding the table will only make the procedure better. The database project cannot simply ignore this because for its nice features to work properly (like resolving references and refactoring renames) it *must* know what table is referred to, and it can't (or won't) adopt SQL Server's own logic for this (which, like I said, is undocumented as far as I know).